# Reorganize the "mountain-climbing" and "climbing" tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging, tag-synonyms

Currently ["mountain-climbing"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/mountain-climbing/info) is a master tag and "climbing" an associated synonym. I suggest it should be the other way round or even better two different (but linked) tags and ask you to discuss this proposal and ultimately [mods to re-organize the tags.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)

Neither tag has a description (that I would like to add after the re-orga) but for me

- mountain climbing is about climbing mountains, ranging from expeditions to hiking as ways to scale a mountain
- climbing is more general, in my humble understanding it includes mountain climbing, rock-climbing or sports climbing (where you climb one length of a rope) in a gym or at an outdoor crag (that can be very different from a mountain), bouldering (again in- and outdoors, you have a mat and climb only low heights so that falling is still safe), ice-climbing (frozen waterfalls or giant freezers), Deep Water Solo (you climb without protection and fall into the water below), climbing trees, what else not ...

To make my point currently there are [24 questions tagged mountain climbing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain-climbing?sort=newest), [some](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6995/bouldering-guide-for-hampi-india) of [which](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7535/what-is-the-indoor-climbing-wall-closest-to-the-centre-of-sydney) have [plain nothing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25748/rock-climbing-when-on-malta) to do with climbing mountains but very well with climbing.

My suggestion is to make two separate tags "climbing" and "mountain-climbing" for now. At least one of these new tags will apply to all old questions. As the site grows eventually new tags such as "rock-climbing", "bouldering", ... might be added but for now I don't deem that necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Please upvote this answer if you agree with the suggestion to make "mountain-climbing" and "climbing" two separate tags and down-vote if you disagree.

For other suggestions please post another answer that can be voted on and comment/answer for discussion.

Comment: Maybe better to name the tag 'mountaineering'? I think its clearer that includes different activities, not just rock climbing. Note on Wikipedia, mountain climbing is a redirect to mountaineering.

Comment: @vclaw great suggestion. I would agree to rename "mountain-climbing" to "mountaineering"

Answer (score 1):

And climbing is not the only tag with questions.
I have been considering public transport, which covers buses and trams but not trains, with high speed rail as a separate tag again.

So if there is a way or method to collect the other 'problem' tags I am happy to help sorting some more.

Comment: +1 (also +1) for mts.  Just as an incidental impact, are Dutch speakers of English likely to associate 'climbing' with 'disembarking' from a train? Or how would they make the distinction?

Comment: Willeke great observation! What do you suggest for the public-transport / trains / hs rail tags? Maybe this would be another good meta question or you could ask a summary question for tags that need a re-organization?

Comment: I like that last, as a Q about every tag group might get a lot of almost identical Q. But I do need to finish a few things I am working on first.

Comment: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3619/which-tags-and-tag-groups-need-attention-where-several-synonyms-or-the-synonyms

Answer (score 1):

Each tag has a Usage guide:

[climbing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climbing) Climbing is the activity of using one's hands, feet, or any other part of the body to ascend a steep object. It is done indoors and out, on natural and manmade structures. It includes mountain climbing/mountaineering, rock-climbing/sports climbing, bouldering, ice-climbing, and many more disciplines

[mountain-climbing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain-climbing) Mountaineering / mountain climbing is about climbing mountains as a sport, ranging from expeditions to hiking as ways to scale a mountain.

Out of 16,822 Open questions at present for 10 to be tagged [climbing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climbing) and 17 [mountain-climbing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain-climbing) (2 with both tags) does not make any sense, in particular with both Usage guides mentioning use for *mountain climbing/mountaineering* or *Mountaineering / mountain climbing*.

Perhaps those who upvoted @mts's answer (ie who voted for the two tags) might care to get together and explain how they envisage the two tags to work, because I think just tag [climbing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climbing) is quite sufficient for the indefinite future.